# Discord.js TypeError: Null is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js, typeerror

I was creating bot using Discord.js v13, but it keeps occurring this error:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).setName(...).setDescription(...).addSubCommand is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Desktop\ReedM\commands\play.js:10:10)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SAMSUNG\Desktop\ReedM\index.js:31:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:10)
```

This is my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders")
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const { QueryType } = require("discord-player")

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("Playing Music")
        .addSubCommand((subcommand) => 
            subcommand.setName("song").setDescription("Search by Url")
            .addStringOption(option => {option.setName("URL").setDescription("Music URL").setRequired(true)}))
```

I tried deleting addStringOption construction, and I also referenced Discord.js v13 Guide

Comment: You are missing a closing } after .setRequired(True)})).
Are you sure u using v13, i've looked into discord guide and everything matches?

Answer (score 1):

You made a typo. It should be [`.addSubcommand()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandBuilder?scrollTo=addSubcommand), not `.addSubCommand()`.